# using timer in MATLAB to extract the system time

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-guide

[image]!I am using MATLAB to design an Analog Clock. Currently, my code simply displays the (or plots rather) the clock design with the hands (hours, mins, secs) and does not tick. Here is my code:

```
function raviClock(h,m,s)
drawClockFace;


%TIMER begins-------
t = timer;
t.ExecutionMode = 'FixedSpacing';  %Use one of the repeating modes
t.Period = 1;                      %Fire on 1 second intervals
t.TimerFcn = @timer_setup;           %When fired, call this function
start(t);
set(gcf,'DeleteFcn',@(~,~)stop(t));
end

function timer_setup(varargin)

format shortg;
timenow = clock;
h = timenow(4);
m = timenow(5);
s = timenow(6);

% hour hand
hours= h + m/60 + s/3600;
hourAngle= 90 - hours*(360/12);

% compute coordinates for pointing end of hour hand and draw it
[xhour, yhour]= polar2xy(0.6, hourAngle);
plot([0 xhour], [0 yhour], 'k-','linewidth',7.4)

% minute hand
mins= m + s/60;
minsAngle= 90 - mins*(360/60);

% compute coordinates for pointing end of minute hand and draw it
[xmins, ymins]= polar2xy(0.75, minsAngle);
plot([0 xmins], [0 ymins], 'r-','linewidth',4)


%second's hand
second = s;
secAngle = 90- second*(360/60);

[xsec, ysec]= polar2xy(0.85, secAngle);
plot([0 xsec], [0 ysec], 'm:','linewidth',2)
%end   % while ends
end

%--------------------------------------------------------

function drawClockFace

%close all          
axis([-1.2 1.2 -1.2 1.2])  
axis square equal
hold on            


theta= 0;
for k= 0:59
    [xX,yY]= polar2xy(1.05,theta);
        plot(xX,yY,'k*')

        [x,y]= polar2xy(0.9,theta);
    if ( mod(k,5)==0 )  % hour mark
        plot(x,y,'<')
    else                % minute mark
        plot(x,y,'r*')
    end
    theta= theta + 360/60;
    end
end

%-----------------------------------------------------------------
function [x, y] = polar2xy(r,theta)

rads= theta*pi/180;  
x= r*cos(rads);
y= r*sin(rads);
end
```

This is simply taking a static data of values for the HOUR, MINUTE and SECOND arguments when i initially call my function. I tried using the following in a while loop but it didn't help much

```
format shortg
c=clock
clockData = fix(c)
h = clockData(4)
m = clockData(5)
s = clockData(6)
```

and passing the h, m and s to the respective cuntions. I want to know how I can use the TIMER obkjects and callbacks for extracting the information of [hrs mins secs] so i can compute the respective point co-ordinates in real time as the clock ticks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd do a couple of things here.

First, you probably don't really need to pass the `h`, `m`, `s` inputs, if you are displaying current time.  Add this to the top of your function to auto set these variables.

```
if nargin == 0
    [~,~,~,h,m,s] = datevec(now);
end
```

Then, it is pretty easy to use a time to call this function periodically.  Something like this.

```
t = timer;
t.ExecutionMode = 'FixedSpacing';  %Use one of the repeating modes
t.Period = 1;                      %Fire on 1 second intervals
t.TimerFcn = @(~,~)raviClock;      %When fired, call this function (ignoring 2 inputs)
start(t);                          %GO!
```

Use `docsearch timer` for in depth documentation of the timer objects.  But the code above should get you started.

To stop the timer, run

```
stop(t);
```

To stop the timer when the window is closed, put the stop command into the window deletion callback:

```
set(gcf,'DeleteFcn',@(~,~)stop(t));  %NOte:  Better to explicitly use a figure number, rather than gcf.
```

Comment: That looks good. But is there a way to stop the timer when the graph window is closed ? I guess if i dont stop the timer i will probably get the graphs over and over again.

Comment: It surely gives me the current time but I get a weird message in MATLAB as    
     '"Error while evaluating TimerFcn for timer 'timer-18'. Too many input arguments. "'
And it only gives me the current time and gives the error, how do i constanttly capture time every second so i can callback my function to change the graph every second ? PLease note, i am now not passing any arguments when I call the function

Comment: Try it now.  I changed the "timerFcn" callback a little bit.

Comment: This change did not work. Previous one was working and was displaying my graph. this change unfortunately does not display my graph. I will show you how my figure looks like so you have a better understanding. I am editing my question to add the figure. Code is already there.

Comment: I made the following changes to your code to get it to work.  1)  Add the `if nargin == 0` block above.  2)  The timer setup needs to occur in a separate function (I tested it from the command line).  As is you are creating a new timer each time.  3)  Replace the original `timerFcn` with `t.TimerFcn = @(~,~)raviClock;`.  That creates a plot with a clock which ticks.

Comment: Furthermore, you need to make the additional changes.  2)  Fix the window that this occurs in, rather then overwriting whatever window is there.  2)  Add the stop-timer-when-window-closes feature (code above) 3) Remove drawing objects from the previous call.  As is this results in all second hand positions displayed at once.

Comment: For some reason, the change in the timer call back @(~,~)raviClock; doesn't seem to work. Can you make the edits in my question, so i get a better understanding of it ? Ive been trying different ways to get away with it but all in vain.

Comment: Okay, I did some changes and made a different function to set the data  for the hands. But now when my second hand moves, the previous position of the hand still exists. Is there a way to erase the previous position of my second hand position ? I am updating my code in the question as edits

Comment: Were you able to change your clock time to setting it to previous time after using the timer function? I am not able to do it.