# Use Tic Toc to Control Loop Speed

Tags: performance, matlab

I am writing a code that is outputting to a DAQ which controls a device. I want to have it send a signal out precisely every 1 second. Depending on the performance of my proccessor the code sometimes takes longer or shorter than 1 second. Is there any way to improve this bit of code? 
Elapsed time is 1.000877 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.992847 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.996886 seconds.

```
for i= 1:100
    tic
    pause(.99)
    toc
end
```

Comment: Short answer to your question is no. Precise timing is very difficult unless you have systems that are dedicated to a single task and that task only. When you run MATLAB, your stuff gets added to the "thread queue" and when your processor gets time to run it, it will. Keep in mind that it is managing thousands of other processes at the same time, so guaranteeing it will happen at exactly 1 second from the previous is near impossible.

Comment: that and using the term "precisely every 1 second" is a rabbit hole because getting it to be exactly 1 instead of 0.99999 or 1.00001 seconds is a pipe dream. And if you are that concerned about time, you are very likely not going to use MATLAB

Comment: maybe [**`timer`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-a-matlab-timer-object.html#f9-38070) or [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980481/using-timer-in-matlab-to-extract-the-system-time) helps you.

Comment: if you want to synchronize an event to some external clock (or trigger), I wouldnt use pause. Look into this documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/daq/multiple-device-synchronization.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `pause` is known to be fairly imprecise (on the order of 10 ms). Matlab in recent versions has optimized `tic toc` to be low-overhead and as precise as possible (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/improvements-to-tic-and-toc-functions-for-measuring-absolute-elapsed-time-performance-in-matlab.html)).

You can make use of `tic toc` to be more precise than pause using the following code:

```
ntimes = 100;
times = zeros(ntimes,1);
time_dur = 0.99;

for i= 1:ntimes
    outer = tic;

    while toc(outer) < time_dur

    end

    times(i) = toc(outer);
end
mean(times)
std(times)
```

Here is my outcome for 50 measurements: `mean = 0.9900` with a `std = 1.0503e-5`, which is much more precise than using pause.

Using the original  code with just pause, for 50 measurements I get: `mean = 0.9981` with a `std = 0.0037`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `start_time = clock();`?

Comment: Good catch, that was when I was trying something else and forgot to delete that line.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that tic toc allows a very precise timing. This solution has a minor clock drift (mean=0.99+4.3563e-05 on my pc) because of resetting the timer, my answer fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a inproved version of shimizu's answer. The main issue is a minimal clock drift. Each iteration the time stamp is taken and then then the timer is reset. The clock drifts by the execution time of these two commands.

A secondary minor improvement combines `pause` and the tic-toc technique to lower the cpu load.

```
ntimes = 100;
times = zeros(ntimes,1);
time_dur = 0.99;
t = tic;
for ix= 1:ntimes
    pause((time_dur*ix-toc(t)-0.1))
    while toc(t) < time_dur*ix
    end
    times(ix) = toc(t);
end
mean(diff(times))
std(diff(times))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your DAQ to update exactly every second, use a DAQ with a FIFO buffer and a clock and configured to read a value from the FIFO exactly once per second.

Even if you got your MATLAB task iterations running exactly one second apart, the inconsistent delay in communication with the DAQ would mess up your timing.